# How do I validate these columns, do i need more complex triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to validate the columns in the table ProjectDetails.TimeCards

```
create table ProjectDetails.TimeCards(
    Time_Card_ID int identity (55,15),
    Employee_ID int foreign key references HumanResources.Employees(Employee_ID),
    Date_Issued date, --DateIssued should be greater than the current date and the project start date (Project start date is from another table). 
    Days_Worked int constraint chk_Days_Worked check(Days_Worked > '0'),
    Project_ID int foreign key references ProjectDetails.Projects(Project_ID),
    Billable_hours int constraint chk_Billable_Hours check (Billable_Hours > '0'),
    Total_Cost money, -- should be automatically calculated by using the following formula: TotalCost=Billable Hours * BillingRate (billing rate is from another table) 
    Work_Code_ID int foreign key references ProjectDetails.WorkCodes(Work_Code_ID)
    );
```

I tried building a trigger, but was only able to get the trigger to fire if the Date_Issued was less than the current date

```
CREATE TRIGGER dateissued
    ON ProjectDetails.TimeCards
    FOR INSERT
    AS
      DECLARE @ModifiedDate date
      SELECT @ModifiedDate = Date_Issued FROM Inserted
          IF (@ModifiedDate < getdate())
          BEGIN
            PRINT 'The modified date should be the current date. Hence, cannot insert.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION -- transaction is to be rolled back
          END
```

i need the trigger to fire if the Date issued is less than the current date and also if date issued is less than the start_date. As for the billing rate calculation i'm lost there.
This is the other table

```
create table ProjectDetails.Projects(
    Project_ID int identity (0100, 01) primary key, -- Primary key
    Project_Name char (50) not null, 
    Start_Date date not null, -- the start date i'm referring to
    End_Date date not null,
    constraint CheckEndLaterThanStart check (End_Date > Start_Date),
    Billing_Estimate money constraint chk_Billing_Estimate check (Billing_Estimate > '1000'),
    Client_ID int Foreign Key references CustomerDetails.Clients(Client_ID)
);
```

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want for the validation.  Sample data can help.

Comment: Careful,`SELECT @ModifiedDate = Date_Issued FROM Inserted` assumes you'll only ever `INSERT` one row at a time.

Comment: When a date is inserted into the table, i need validations that would ensure it is greater than the current date and also greater than the start date which is on another table

Comment: On a different note, you probably don't want `Total_Cost` calculated in your table; as it's based off values in a different table. That sounds like a candidate for a `VIEW`.

Comment: What "other table"? You've only given us DDL for one.

Comment: yeah, I'm not doing batch insert for now, even if i was using batch insert i don't know how to make it accept values greater than the current date and start date

Comment: Sorry my bad, i'll add the other table

Comment: Never assume your `INSERT` will only ever include 1 row, as the moment it doesn't (and that will happen)the behaviour you're expecting won't happen.

Comment: @Larnu I've included the code for the 'other table'

Comment: noted @Larnu. I would have to read up more on batch insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this provides the logic you are after. There are a couple of comments in the code for you:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_chk_Date_Issued ON ProjectDetails.TimeCards
FOR INSERT, UPDATE --I assume on need on UPDATE as well, as otherwise this won't validate
AS BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM inserted i
                   JOIN ProjectDetails.Projects P ON i.Project_ID = P.Project_ID
              WHERE i.Date_Issued < CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) 
                 OR i.Date_Issued < P.Start_Date) BEGIN
       RAISERROR(N'Date Issued cannot be less than the current date or the Project Start Date.', 10,1); --Raised an error, rather than using PRINT
       ROLLBACK;
    END
END
```

Note that you may want a different trigger for `UPDATE`, as if you are updating the row, and `Date_Issued` has a value lower than the date of the `UPDATE`, the statement will fail.

Comment: If i may ask what does the 10, 1 at the end of the raiseerror statement mean?

Comment: @Shayooluwah [RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Shayooluwah Your code includes: `--DateIssued should be greater than the current date and the project start date (Project start date is from another table).` so you can only hire people in the future, not today. The project must also have been around for at least a day. That means the comparisons should be `<=` rather than `<`. _Free beer tomorrow._